# Identities for Euclidean norms

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces

Maybe I am looking too closely and am failing to utilise some known identities but I wish to prove *elegantly* that for any $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$\frac{a}{2}\|Y\|^2-aX\cdot Y = \frac{a}{2}\left(\|Y-X\|^2-\|X\|^2\right),$$
where $X\cdot Y = X^TY $.

The identity is easy to show when manually unwinding the Euclidean norms into their sums however I cannot help be feel there is a much easier way to show this!

If anything is unclear about my question please let me know!

Comment: Write all the squared norms as dot products and expand using distributivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
\Vert y- x \Vert^2 - \Vert x \Vert^2 &= (y-x-x) \cdot(y-x+x)\\
&=(y-2x)\cdot y\\
&=\Vert y \Vert^2- 2x \cdot y
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This was great! Thank you :)